# React Native not accepting fonts imported with useFonts hook

Tags: react-native, expo, font-family

I imported some custom font files with useFonts with expo cli, but there's an error saying,

> fontFamily "ProductSans" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Here's the code

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

const FontScreen= () => {

  const [customFonts] = useFonts({
    ProductSans: '../../assets/fonts/ProductSansRegular.ttf',
    ProductSansBold: '../../assets/fonts/ProductSansBold.ttf',
  });

<Text style={{fontFamily: 'ProductSans' }}>Text</Text>
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does this solve your problem?
[How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172404)

Answer (score 1):

The `useFonts()` hook works like so:

```
useFonts(map: string | {
    [fontFamily: string]: FontSource;
}): [boolean, Error | null]

Load a map of custom fonts to use in textual elements. 
The map keys are used as font names, and can be used with fontFamily: <name>;. 
It returns a boolean describing if all fonts are loaded.

Note, the fonts are not "reloaded" when you dynamically change the font map.
```

Since the `customFonts` is a boolean that describes if the fonts are loaded, you should only apply the font if `customFonts` is true. Also, make sure to surround your font paths with the `require` function to load them properly:

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

const FontScreen = () => {

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    ProductSans: require('../../assets/fonts/ProductSansRegular.ttf'),
    ProductSansBold: require('../../assets/fonts/ProductSansBold.ttf'),
  });

 return (
    <>
        {fontsLoaded && <Text style={{fontFamily: 'ProductSans'}}>
            Text
         </Text>
    </>
}
```

You could also have the expo loading screen show while `fontsLoaded` is false:

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

const FontScreen = () => {

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    ProductSans: require('../../assets/fonts/ProductSansRegular.ttf'),
    ProductSansBold: require('../../assets/fonts/ProductSansBold.ttf'),
  });

 if (!fontsLoaded) {
     return <AppLoading />;
 }

 return (
    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'ProductSans'}}>
            Text
    </Text>
}
```

More info [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/).